# Há como executar um único comando como administrador (sem ser o programa inteiro)?

Tags: windows, golang

Não queria executar o programa inteiro com privilégio de administrador, por razão de segurança e por conveniência.

Entretanto preciso executar um comando:

```
exec.Command(`cmd`, `/c`, `CheckNetIsolation.exe`, `LoopbackExempt`, `-a`, `-n=....`)
```

Isto APENAS funciona quando o programa abre "como administrador". Isso é, eu tenho abrir o `meu-programa.exe` como administrador para que o comando funcione. Sem isso, ele resulta um erro.

Todo o programa roda sem a permissão de administrador, EXCETO por esse código acima. Ele é o único comando que requer esse privilégio.

---

Não faz muito sentido ter que abrir como administrador só por causa de uma única linha de código, sendo que tudo funcionaria sem ele.

Existe alguma forma, de APENAS exigir o administrador para executar esse comando? Isso é, alguma coisa como (isso não existe!):

```
exec.Command(`cmd`, `/c`, `/admin`, `....`)
```

Isso é, o `/admin` faria aparecer aquela "tela" solicitando o usuário autorização para executar como administrador... Enfim, o programa inteiro ainda estaria sem os privilégios e só este comando seria executado como administrador.

**Existe alguma coisa parecida?**

Eu já notei que alguns programas, durante a execução e em algum momento aleatório, exigem que conceda permissão de administrador. Como isso é feito, é algo similar à este caso?

---

Note: Todo o programa é apenas um único `.exe`, sem `.dll` ou outros `.exe` ou afins. Eu posso até incluir outros arquivos (como um `.bat`) e extrai-lo em tempo de execução, mas não sei se é uma boa forma, mas talvez facilite o processo.

Comment: Só olhei por cima, veja se tem haver... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558066/how-to-ask-for-administer-privileges-on-windows-with-go

Comment: Há a possibilidade de abrir esse programa com [powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-7.1#example-5--start-powershell-as-an-administrator)

Comment: Creio que esses outros programas tem internamente dentro deles mini-programas ou então é instalado junto, sendo interno é "extraido" (ou gerado) no TMP do sistema operacional e executado provavelmente usando o comando start (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) para executar como admin (solicitar ao UAC), o programa PAI, deve ter um sinal de comunicação com o "filho" (o extraido), o pai provavelmente espera um sinal do filho, e o filho fechar arbitrariamente ele também detecta. Por fim, esse sinal deve ser um "socket" simples ou até um arquivo.

Comment: Creio que isso já lhe de um norte de como desenvolver algo.

Comment: Sua 'Note' não corresponde o que é praticado, até porque linguagem Rust e Go que são modernas possuem interoperabilidade com C/C++ e wrappers. Go tem a biblioteca padrão syscall, para carregar Dlls e assim fazer chamadas. Em projetos complexos e coerente dividir pra conquistar, pra a analogia, as camadas de redes de TCP/IP foram criadas justamente por ser inviável fazer tudo junto e misturado.

Comment: @aldison O que enfatizo é um único executável, dê dois cliques e execute a aplicação, sem uso de instaladores ou outras dependência. É possível carregar DLLs, não disse que não é. O problema é que, se não for estática, será necessário inclui-las dentro da aplicação (como `var DLL = []byte{ a dll }`,  NESTE CASO. Então extrai-la e utilizar o `windows.NewLazyDLL`. Isso funciona, mas continua "um único .exe". Então, se houver dois `.exe`, o segundo estaria dentro do primeiro (`var SegundoEXE = ...` :P), como o @Guilherme Nascimento mencionou. O problema disso é que parece meio overkill.

Comment: @Inkeliz compreendo! fiz um update na resposta, percebi que é possível com GOROUTINE, e parabéns pela pergunta.

Comment: Só um detalhe, ao invés de usar PHYSICALDRIVE0 seria preferível usar TMP, vale lembrar que que se tiver multiplos usuários acessando a máquina, seja duas contas logadas ou até uma logada e outra "remota" já vai ter problemas, tudo isso exige uma atenção e terá problemas se não o fizer, tanto que por isso não formulei a resposta, pq é algo que depende de uma série de situações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim ser admin, há esse gist de [Jeremy Black](https://gist.github.com/jerblack/d0eb182cc5a1c1d92d92a4c4fcc416c6)

Para ver o resultado do commando, adicione `.CombinedOutput()` ao final de `exec.Command(args).CombineOutput()`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "syscall"

    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    if !amAdmin() {
        runMeElevated()
    } else {
        res, _ := exec.Command(`cmd`, `/c`, `CheckNetIsolation.exe`, `LoopbackExempt`, `-a`, `-n=....`).CombinedOutput()
        fmt.Println(string(res))
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

func runMeElevated() {
    verb := "runas"
    exe, _ := os.Executable()
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    args := strings.Join(os.Args[1:], " ")

    verbPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(verb)
    exePtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(exe)
    cwdPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(cwd)
    argPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(args)

    var showCmd int32 = 1 //SW_NORMAL

    err := windows.ShellExecute(0, verbPtr, exePtr, argPtr, cwdPtr, showCmd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func amAdmin() bool {
    _, err := os.Open("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("admin no")
        return false
    }
    fmt.Println("admin yes")
    return true
}
```

Como você gostaria de um admin temporário, o ideal é criar outro executável:

```
AppFolder
  --programa1.exe // normal sem privilégios
  --programa2.exe // solicitará privilégios
```

Programa 1:

```
func main() {
    local, _ := os.Getwd()
    call := fmt.Sprintf("%s/programa2.exe", local)
    exec.Command(`cmd`, `/c`, call)
}
```

Programa 2:

```
func main() {
    if !amAdmin() {
        runMeElevated()
    } else {
        res, _ := exec.Command(`cmd`, `/c`, `CheckNetIsolation.exe`, `LoopbackExempt`, `-a`, `-n=....`).CombinedOutput()

        file, _ := os.OpenFile("result.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
        file.Write(res)
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

pra ficar livre de outros 'exes' observei que é possivel utilizando goroutine:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
func main() {

    wg.Add(1)
    go goroutineAdmin()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Programa continua executando sem privilegios")
    //check
    amAdmin()

}

func goroutineAdmin() {
    if !amAdmin() {
        runMeElevated()
        wg.Done()
    } else {
        res, _ := exec.Command(`cmd`, `/c`, `CheckNetIsolation.exe`, `LoopbackExempt`, `-a`, `-n=....`).CombinedOutput()

        file, _ := os.OpenFile("result.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
        file.Write(res)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Achei uma solução baseada no [@Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques), que é de utilizar o PowerShell.

---

É possível utilizar o `Start-Process` combinado com o `-Verb RunAs`, para executar como administrador. Mas, tem um porém, **você não consegue obter o resultado**. É possível obter o resultado quando utiliza o `-NoNewWindow`, mas isto não funciona combinado com o `-Verb RunAs`. Uma alternativa seria utilizar, através do CMD, algo como `> SeuArquivo.txt` e então ler este aquivo depois.

No meu caso, especificamente, não é necessário obter o retorno do comando diretamente. O resultado pode ser obtido usando outro comando, como `CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s`, então verificando o que solicitou consta na lista e esta ação não requer permissão administrativa.

---

No total, ao invés de:

```
exec.Command(`cmd`, `/c`, `CheckNetIsolation.exe`, `LoopbackExempt`, `-a`, `-n=....`)
```

Ficou:

```
exec.Command(
   `powershell.exe`, 
   `-Command`,
   `Start-Process cmd '/c CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n=....' -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle hidden -Wait`,
)
```

Em geral ficaria:

```
exec.Command(
   `powershell.exe`, 
   `-Command`,
   `Start-Process cmd '/c {{O QUE VOCÊ QUER EXECUTAR}}' -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle hidden -Wait`,
)
```

Isso foi o suficiente. Agora, ao executar é solicitado os direitos de administrador, somente para execução do `cmd '/c CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n=....'`. Isso não afeta a aplicação principal, que continua sem os direitos administrativos.

---

No meu caso, não é necessário resposta (o stdout?!), mas se for necessário pode usar algo como:

```
name := make([]byte, 24)
rand.Read(name)

path := filepath.Join(os.TempDir(), hex.EncodeToString(name))
defer os.Remove(path)


err = exec.Command(
    `powershell.exe`, 
    `-Command`,
    `Start-Process cmd '/c CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n=.... > `+path+`' -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle hidden -Wait`).Run()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

result, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Não é muito elegante, mas parece funcional.

---

Ainda estou vendo se há algum problema, mas parece funcionar.